# grails domain class afterload saving the values in DB

Tags: class, events, grails, dns

Hi I need to decrypt the values, before showing to UI. for the same i trying to decrypt the values in Domain class  afterLoad() event. however those decrypted values getting saved in DB.  Please tell me how to stop that?

Answer (score 3):

You can just implement getters for fields, decrypt and return values in getters. And still simply access values by field name.
It will solve your problem and IMHO the better way.

Answer (score 1):

Grails automatically saves objects - you can prevent that by using read() instead of get().

Although, I would suggest keeping decrypted values in separate [transient](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/transients.html) properties.

Comment: thanks for suggestion.  Domain class is class Employee { String firstname  String lastname def afterLoad() {
        def lst = dataEncryption.getEncryptColumns()
        String val ;
                        val =firstname
                        String deval = dataEncryption.decryptData()
                        firstname = deval
                    }
                }catch (Exception ex){
                }            }        }    }    ,I can't make firstname as transient field.